# Visual Studio Properties Panel

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio

What is the name of the UI component that Visual Studio has for it's Properties panel? I want to use exactly the same component they have.

When i right click on a component on a Windows Form and click Properties, a panel shows up to set properties. The Visual Studio uses a component to display the properties of the UI component, what is the latter component's name?

Please any help!

Comment: Yes the one you use to set the properties of the UI components.

Comment: It is a PropertyGrid. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx .. and I don't get why you close this as "unclear", it is pretty obvious what is asked here.

Comment: [`PropertyGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx)?

Comment: Why are you people down voting me for the question, is it a bad question? Thanks Timbo that's what i'm looking for.

Comment: @hiddenUser - what have you tried?

Comment: Consider posting an answer guys.

Comment: It looks like every question in SO is downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for a [PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx#usingpropgrid_topic1).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I pressed <kbd>F4</kbd> and it re-appeared!